# R tm package tm.plugin.tags stopped working

Tags: r, tm

I use the tm.plugin.tags for sentiment analysis:

```
pos=sapply(search.corpus,tm_tag_score,tm_get_tags("Positiv"))
neg=sapply(search.corpus,tm_tag_score,tm_get_tags("Negativ"))
```

Somehow it stopped working on my Linux machine. The library loads without warnings, and is shown as loaded in the packages view of RStudio. However the functions are not available:

```
No documentation for ‘tm_tag_score’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??tm_tag_score’
```

However, the same script is working fine in Windows. 
Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read here: http://cran.fyxm.net/web/packages/tm/news.html - it has been renamed into `tm_term_score` in the `tm` package.

```
library(tm)
tm_tag_score <- tm_term_score
```

(What a coincidence; I ran into the same problem about 2 hours ago.)

Comment: Thanks! I was pulling my hair out here. Found it 2 hours ago, could not find the solution. Coincidence indeed!